# jQuery Video in Lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I'm building a lightbox and have reached adding support for flash and videos. I've never had any demands or need for video, so honestly don't know where to begin. I do know I have to be able to serve different video formats for different browsers, but don't know how to approach this. I'm also hoping to have this work in "non-modern" browsers. The tutorials and questions I've found are very vague any typically result in "try using this plugin". Perhaps someone could help by explaining how i would go about loading a video that would be browser compatible, and possibly the video formats i should be supporting? Or a link :) thanks!

Comment: Are you also writing server side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just did the same thing. I used a combination of [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) and [Video for Everybody](http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody).

Basically, the idea behind Video for Everybody is that you use the HTML5 `video` tag with an embedded flash video player for browsers that do not support HTML5 video.  For the embedded flash player, I used [JWPlayer](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players).

And then you just make something like `<a href="#videoPlayer" class="video_link">Play Video</a>` and point Fancybox at the link. Voila, you've got a video in an Fancybox (which is about the same thing as Lightbox).

For cross-browser compatibility, [you should offer the file in MP4 (using H.264 codec) and WebM or Ogg](http://html5doctor.com/multimedia-troubleshooting/#video-support). Older browsers that do not support HTML5 videos will use the flash player fallback with the MP4 file anyways.

One thing to keep in mind with your MP4 file is that often the [moov atom](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/video/articles/mp4_movie_atom.html) is placed at the end of the file, so the file cannot start playing until it has fully downloaded. Use a tool like [qt-faststart](http://multimedia.cx/eggs/improving-qt-faststart/) to move it to the beginning of the file, allowing it to start playing before fully downloaded.

---

**Example:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("a.video_link").fancybox();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#videoPlayer" class="video_link">Play video</a>
    <video width="640" height="360" controls id="videoPlayer">
        <source src="__VIDEO__.MP4" type="video/mp4" />
        <source src="__VIDEO__.OGV" type="video/ogg" />
        <object width="640" height="360" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="__FLASH__.SWF">
            <param name="movie" value="__FLASH__.SWF" />
            <param name="flashvars" value="controlbar=over&amp;image=__POSTER__.JPG&amp;file=__VIDEO__.MP4" />
            <img src="__VIDEO__.JPG" width="640" height="360" alt="__TITLE__" title="No video playback capabilities, please download the video below" />
        </object>
    </video>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So am I supposed to manually convert all videos to multiple formats for html5 compatibility? Is there any way to automate this step?

Comment: Dunno about an automating it, but I used [Miro Video Converter](http://www.mirovideoconverter.com/).